# How to send requests with varying number of payload elements while reaching a desired average of all elements at the end of the script?

Tags: algorithm, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, jsr223

I have a need to continuously generate the same HTTP request over a defined duration but with a random varying number of objects in the body (within a 1-99 range), on each thread loop and my requirement is that at the end of the script I should end up with a calculated average of 3 such objects. So I think that I need to somehow store the number of objects from each HTTP request (under concurrent heavy load) and then influence the creation of these objects during runtime so that I may reach my goal of 3 at the end of the script duration.

In Jmeter, I have a HTTP Request Sampler with some static XML body and some variable which holds a place in which I insert dynamically generated data. I have a JSR223 Preprocessor as a child element for the purpose of the dynamical data generation. That preprocessor has code which can generate one XML node or more based on an int parameter. If I say I want to create 2 XML nodes, I set that parameter to 2. I can create 1 or 99 such nodes. Then I insert this XML nodes into the body payload of the HTTP Request Sampler in the variable place, on each request.

Example of what I call XML nodes. In this example I have 3 such nodes. One node is between   tags:

```
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00001'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='555551555' name='Braiden' date='12/31/2022' />
  </object>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00002'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='100000001' name='Dominique' date='12/10/2024' />
  </object>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00003'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='100000002' name='Joyce' date='11/15/2025' />
  </object>
```

My need is to generate HTTP requests with varying XML nodes in the body each time, but at the end of the script duration, I should end up with a calculated number of 3 .

I know that I can do a random function between 1 and 99 to generate random nodes inside my HTTP request body on each run, but I don't know how to control the average number of nodes as the script is running so that by the time the script is over I would end up with a number of sent samples and these samples should have bodies with varying content nodes between 1 and 99, but on average the calculated result should be 3.

For example let's say that I send the same HTTP request with 2 threads and 5 loops, so 10 times in total, but of those 10 times, the body of the request contained 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 XML nodes. On average this would be 5.5, but I don't know how to measure and control/influence this result according to my wants from JMeter.

How could JMeter check the average and control/influence the nodes generation on each request so that on average after the script has run for a certain duration (2hours) this average becomes what I want it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible because you don't know how many iterations will happen in 2 hours. You can get quite close to 3, but if the number of calls fluctuates the mean will fluctuate as well.

If you switch to fixed number of iterations from 2 hours execution you could go for:

- Pre-generating the data set like it's described in the [Generate random number by given certain mean and standard deviation in Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2472-excel-random-number-mean-standard-deviation.html) article and then using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to read the number of elements in the current message
- If you want to do it in JMeter runtime take a look at [Random.nextGaussian()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian--) function, you can control the standard deviation by multiplication and mean by addition like

  ```
   nextGaussian() * desiredStandardDeviation + desiredMean
  ```

Comment: Hi. I would like to do it in JMeter runtime. I read that documentation but I don't really understand it. I tried this formula provided by you , set def desiredMean = 3
def desiredStandardDeviation = 1 and I when I print the fromula outcome I get results such as 1.3938969636555867, 2.824762034825056, 3.1335641947228394 etc ; I don't get how I ca use this to achieve what I want.
Would you mind giving me an example with an outcome?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to this issue in the following way:

1. I defined an array of 100 numbers which if used to calculated the average will give a number of 3

`def payloadElementsCount = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 10, 20, 30, 99]`

2. I get the tread number and use the modulo operator to get the reminder of the division of each thread number with 100

   int tNumber = ctx.getThreadNum()

   def elementsConfiguration = tNumber % 100

So, for example:

```
1%100 = 1
2%100 = 2
50%100 = 50
99%100 = 99
100%100 = 0
101%100 = 1
etc
```

This way I get a number of potential elements from 0 to 99 every time a thread executes the code from the JSR223 sampler.

Then, I can use this potential number of elements as an index to get a value from my defined array and assign this value to the `requiredElements` valuable which will ultimately dictate how many elements will be generated by the current sample.

Example:

- When the thread number will be 99, I will get 99 as index, and according to my defined array

  payloadElementsCount[99] = 99
- When the thread number will be 98, I will get 98 as index, and according to my defined array

  payloadElementsCount[98] = 30

Since I have only 100 numbers in my array and I know upfront that their average is 3 , then at every 100 samples (requests) the average will be 3.

```
def requiredElements = payloadElementsCount[elementsConfiguration]
```

Maybe this helps someone, sometime.